Issues Connecting to Spirent TestCenter Using Java and Tcl
I'm having trouble connecting to Spirent TestCenter (STC) using both Java and Tcl scripts. Here are the steps I've taken and the errors I'm encountering:
Using Java:
I tried running a script Java with the following command:
shell
java.exe "-Dstc.dir=C:/Program Files/Spirent Communications/Spirent TestCenter 5.16/Spirent TestCenter Application" main.java

The script fails with the following exception:

Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: in init: Cannot create request.
SAL is not connected to a Test Session or a Server Manager. The
failure occurs specifically when the stc.Init() function is called.

Using Tcl:
I attempted to run a Tcl script with the following command:
shell
tclsh xxx.tcl

The script sources the Spirent TestCenter library:
source {C:\Program Files\Spirent Communications\Spirent TestCenter 5.16\Spirent TestCenter Application\SpirentTestCenter.tcl}

The error message I receive is:

This error is likely due to an invalid STC_SERVER_ADDRESS,
STC_SESSION_NAME, or STC_SESSION_ADDRESS environment variable value,
or a mismatched STC client version. STC_SERVER_ADDRESS = 192.168.2.102
STC_SESSION_NAME = NEW_TEST_SESSION STC_SESSION_ADDRESS =
192.168.2.102 Current STC client version: 5.16.0166.0000 Spirent: 15:46:46.564 ERROR - in init: Cannot create request. SAL is not
connected to a Test Session or a Server Manager.

Questions:
Could there be an issue with my environment variable settings?
How can I verify and correct the environment variables?
What other steps should I take to troubleshoot this connection issue?

Looks like both clients are reporting the same error, which is being reported by the STC service. I guess you need to read the service logs to progress this; it probably isn't a client problem.

I had the log reporting:
2024-07-17T01:35:46.976Z ERROR 14968    - user.scripting       - Unable to connect to Remote Test Session at 192.168.2.102:80
I guess the error is raised due to a wrong test session. The default port is 40008, which is also failed before. I didn't find the description of it in document, is it the address of STC like STC_SERVER_ADDRESS ?

I added JAVA related environment variable and then the connection succeed. Still, I am not sure how it worked.
